# error with cv2.face.mindistancepredictcollector()

Tags: python, face-recognition, opencv3.1

I have installed opencv 3.1.0 with extra modules, but when I try to use

```
>>> s = cv2.face.MinDistancePredictCollector()
```

it returns an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
s.MinDistancePredictCollector()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'MinDistancePredictCollector'
```

I also checked the documentation:

```
>>> help(cv2.face)
Help on module cv2.face in cv2:

NAME
    cv2.face

FILE
    (built-in)

FUNCTIONS
    StandardCollector_create(...)
    StandardCollector_create([, threshold]) -> retval

    createEigenFaceRecognizer(...)
    createEigenFaceRecognizer([, num_components[, threshold]]) -> retval

    createFisherFaceRecognizer(...)
    createFisherFaceRecognizer([, num_components[, threshold]]) -> retval

    createLBPHFaceRecognizer(...)
    createLBPHFaceRecognizer([, radius[, neighbors[, grid_x[, grid_y[,    threshold]]]]]) -> retval
```

and I found out that `MinDistancePredictCollector()` does not exist. So how can I install it?

Answer (score 3):

I just asked the same problem on [Github](https://github.com/rragundez/PyData/issues/6) and it can be solved by the following code:

```
if cv2.__version__ >= "3.1.0":
    collector = cv2.face.StandardCollector_create()
    recognizer.predict_collect(face_img, collector)
    conf = collector.getMinDist()
    pred = collector.getMinLabel()
else:     # older version
    pred, conf = recognizer.predict(face_img)
```