# opencv3.1 on windows. object has no attribute 'MinDistancePredictCollector'

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, opencv3.1

I'm using OpenCV3.1 with python27 on Windows 7 for face recognition. I compile the OpenCV 3.1 and the opencv_contrib modules using CMAKE and VS Express 2012 with all teh required stuff. Until I reach to the last part, which is for the collector to calculate the matching picture to the database or more specifically this line:

collector = cv2.face.MinDistancePredictCollector()

and outputting this error:

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'MinDistancePredictCollector'

Comment: Where did you get the source code that you used to build your copy of OpenCV? GitHub? If so, what exact version did you use, because I can see [significant changes](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/commit/48903ef96d37ae2b9716268e0975943fe83c194f#diff-d9c561bf45c255c5951ff1ab55e80473L171) in that module between tag 3.1.0 and master.

Comment: i got it from github for both master and the contrib modules.

Comment: What i meant by "master" was the [master branch](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/tree/master) of the contrib module (that's what we're dealing with here after all). This is the in-development version of the code, which as I mentioned above contains breaking changes. You need to use the [tag 3.1.0](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/tree/3.1.0) to get something that your code will work with (and that most examples will target). Same will apply to the main opencv library -- go for the tag. Being on bleeding edge is tricky, as you just found out.

Comment: Thanks @DanMašek problem solved. I download and use module from the [tag 3.1.0](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/tree/3.1.0) and then recompile it again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error with cv2.face.mindistancepredictcollector()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38797210/error-with-cv2-face-mindistancepredictcollector)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to @DanMasek reply on my question. Which is to download the proper module [tag 3.1.0](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/tree/3.1.0) and recompile it. problem solved.